# Azure Logs Kusto Query Output to database table

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, kusto-explorer

I need to save a output from a Kusto query on monitoring logs into a database table but I am unable to find a way to do it. I am presuming there will be a way to get the output from a Kusto query and save it to storage then pull that data into a table using a pipeline.

Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:
Firstly, I have executed below Kusto query and exported it into csv file into local machine:

```
 AzureActivity
 | project OperationName,Level,ActivityStatus
```

[image]

And then uploaded the csv file from local machine into my Blob storage account as below:

[image]

Now I created an ADF service

now create new pipeline in it and take `Copy activity` in that pipeline.

[image]

Then I created linked service for blob storage as source and linked service for SQL database as sink.

In source dataset I gave the Blob file

[image]

In source dataset I gave SQL server table

[image]

Copy activity sink settings set table options as Auto create table

[image]

**Output In SQL Query editor:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So what we do not is we have created a logic application that runs the query real-time and returns the data via http then we save that to the table. No manual intervention